# Scratches appear on vector logo on Safari

Tags: svg, vector, responsive-design, safari, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing an eCommerce platform for one of my customers, I have to implement a retina-responsive logo (vector format, svg), everything is working fine on Firefox, Chrome and IE but not Safari (iOS & OS X), many scratches are appearing, here is a screenshot:

http://i.imgur.com/mpGdXD8.png?1

Regarding the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="header_logo" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-{4+$warehouse_vars.logo_width}{if isset($warehouse_vars.logo_position) && !$warehouse_vars.logo_position} col-sm-push-{4-$warehouse_vars.logo_width/2} centered-logo  {/if}">
<a href="{if $force_ssl}{$base_dir_ssl}{else}{$base_dir}{/if}" title="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
<img class="logo img-responsive" src="{$img_dir}/logo.svg"  data-fallback="{$logo_url}" alt="{$shop_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
</a>
</div>
```

The e-commerce solution is based on Prestashop 1.6.0.14.
The logo was initially built using Photoshop then vectorised with Inkspace.

Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure this is a code related problem. Do you have a retina screen? AFAIK retina logos should be twice the size of normal logo. You will probably get better answers on another stackexchange: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Whatever is wrong, is almost certainly wrong with the SVG file. Can you post a link to it?

Comment: Did you try create it again? but not vectorize, do it from the start with inkscape, see when you vectorize something with inkscape, makes a very large file creating many layers with colors.

Comment: Five me a few minutes to send you the .svg logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I created for you the Logo, with Inkscape:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/5adsdwl9a3zeidu/Mytech_Logo.svg

Download it and test it, should work.

Usually **when you vectorize with inkscape** it creates many layers with different colors, this makes the file very large, compare the file size of your logo, and the one that i sent to you, that one have around **10KB**, and some times vectorized files could lack in some browsers, caused for all those layers and the **background transparency**, probably IE9 have this problem too, or some other browsers.

Instead try to create it directly with Inskcape, the vectorize method is not usually the best option, if you want to implement it on the web, as i told you before:

Creates **very large files**.

Also if you use the option "smooth", It will seem with blured borders.
And if you don't use it the edges will seem rough, of that way it loses the retina concept, at the end there won't be a difference between a .jpg and .svg file.

**Hope been helpful!**

Comment: Thank you so much, it fits beautifully on the website. I’m not very familiar with Inkscape, I have been trying to work it out with Photoshop and Illustrator, but have been stuck trying to vectorise it and make it fit without problems in some browsers: Safari, ..
Again, thank you so much.

Comment: When you finish your project, i would like to see it, may you could give me the link.